# Rails redirecting invalid route to root

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

If my website is `www.foo.com` if the user types `www.foo.com/blahblahblah` it will say that `/blahblahblah` is an invalid path (obviously).  But I want it instead to redirect to the root_path so that the controller can process the URL -- the page `www.foo.com` should be rendered I want to pull the text `blahblahblah` and do something with it.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several possibilities. Here's one. You could add this to the **bottom** of your routes.rb:

```
match ':not_found' => 'my_controller#index',
  :constraints => { :not_found => /.*/ }
```

which will establish a catch-all route to make MyController's index action handle any missing paths; it can detect them by looking at `params[:not_found]` and doing whatever it wants, such as redirecting to the root_path (`redirect_to root_url`), redirecting somewhere strategically based on the bad path, rendering something special, examining the referrer/referer for clues about the source, etc.

The `:constraints` option is necessary; otherwise the `not_found` param won't be able to contain special characters like slashes and dots.

Put this at the bottom of your routes because, obviously, it will match everything, and you want to give your other routes first crack at the path.

If you only want to redirect, nothing more, you could do this instead (again, at the **bottom**):

```
match ':not_found' => redirect('/'), :constraints => { :not_found => /.*/ }
```

Comment: Is ':not_found' a special string for rails?  And where can I read more about it?

Comment: Nope, nothing special. You can name it whatever you want.

Comment: Oh so what lets it match everything is the "constraint" (hardly) of not_found being able to match everything (regex /.*/).  Thank you very much by the way this helped a lot!

Comment: In newer versions of rails need to specify like this: match ':not_found' => redirect('/'), :constraints => { :not_found => /.*/ }, via: :get

Answer (score 6):

in rails 4 
  get '*path' => redirect('/')