# Rails reading url query string from invalid route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This question is a follow-up question to my previous one that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548928/rails-redirecting-invalid-route-to-root).  If I have a website `www.foo.com` and the user types in `www.foo.com/blahblahblah` I want it to redirect to the root path and be able to manipulate the text `blahblahblah`.  I used the solution proposed on that question by Rob Davis and it works correctly for the most part -- if the user types in something like `www.foo.com/a/b/c` it redirects to the root path and the string `a/b/c` is correctly being stored in `params[:not_found]`.  However, if the user enters something with a question mark, like `www.foo.com/a?b=c` then all that gets stored in `params[:not_found]` is `a` and `?b=c` vanishes.  How do I ensure that question mark or not, all the text after `www.foo.com/` gets stored in `params[:not_found]`?

Again, please first [read the question and the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548928/rails-redirecting-invalid-route-to-root).  Then if you can answer this question that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails routes can only match patches, not querystrings.

If you use the first example Rob Davis gave you (the one without the redirect), you'll be able to inspect the querystring parameters using:

```
request.query_string
```

Check this, might be useful as well: [Rails Routing with Query String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257839/rails-routing-with-query-string)